# Pausing a non playing video removes thumbnail - postMessage Javascript Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I noticed pausing a video which is not being played results in the removal of its preview / thumbnail image.

I'm using [the Javascript Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=es#Requirements) for that.

Is there a way to prevent it using the API ?
I would prefer not having to check if the video is playing or not, because that would imply much more code.

I would probably have to use the `new YT.player()` function, load the Youtube API dynamically, listen to the `onStateChange` event, keep a list of possible videos and their states...

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/h9o1g2c5/)

```
$('#pauseVideo').click(function(){
    pauseVideo();
});

function pauseVideo(){
    var video = $('#myVideo');
    var element = video.get(0);

    if (/youtube\.com\/embed\//.test(video.attr('src'))) {
        video.get(0).contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro, are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @d.datul1990 yeap. Just check the fiddle to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert the link directly as an iframe most of the options work as *GET* [parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters). Try to add `controls=0&showinfo=0` to the video url.

The supported value for `showinfo` are `0` and `1`. If the player is loading a playlist, and you explicitly set the parameter value to 1, then, upon loading, the player will also display thumbnail images for the videos in the playlist. Note that this functionality is only supported for the AS3 player.

Or

Try to use `cueVideoById` method of [queuing functions for videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Queueing_Functions). This function loads the specified video's thumbnail and prepares the player to play the video.

- **Argument syntax**

  ```
  player.cueVideoById(videoId:String,
  startSeconds:Number,
  suggestedQuality:String):Void
  ```
- **Object syntax**

  ```
  player.cueVideoById({videoId:String,
  startSeconds:Number,
  endSeconds:Number,
  suggestedQuality:String}):Void
  ```

Comment: None of those solutions seems to solve the problem when stopping the video. [Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9o1g2c5/2/) with showinfo=1.